# aws s3 credentials and grantee drgn

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to using aws, specifically the aws s3.

if I want to set my php script/site to put an object into the bucket, should I set a specific grantee? if so, what should the grantee be?

or its supposed to work right after I've created the security access key.

Thanks,
ed

Comment: What do you mean by specific grantee?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Upload an object by streaming the contents of a file
// $pathToFile should be absolute path to a file on disk
$result = $client->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'     => $bucket,
    'Key'        => 'data_from_file.txt',
    'SourceFile' => $pathToFile,
    'Metadata'   => array(
        'Foo' => 'abc',
        'Baz' => '123'
    )
));

// We can poll the object until it is accessible
$client->waitUntil('ObjectExists', array(
    'Bucket' => $this->bucket,
    'Key'    => 'data_from_file.txt'
));
```

Take a look at above example, essentially this is what you need. AWS S3-PHP SDK doc has all the examples covered  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html

Hope it helps